# How to select all books of autor?

Tags: mysql

I have tables:

**RUBRIC:** `RubricID, RubricName`

**AUTOR:** `AutorID, FirstName, LastName`

**BOOK:** `BookID, BookName, book_photo`

**BOOKAUTOR:** `BookID, AutorID`

**BOOKRUBRIC:** `BookID, RubricID`

And I have no idea how to select all books of one autor who wrote this books.
I jast can write like this

```
select distinct book.BookName, autor.LastName
    from autor, book
    where autor.LastName = book name;
```

But it is wrong. I know that I need to use JOIN but I can't understand how? plaese help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to:

```
SELECT book.BookName, autor.LastName
    FROM book
    LEFT JOIN bookautor ON bookautor.BookID = book.BookID 
    LEFT JOIN autor ON bookautor.AutorID = autor.AutorID
    WHERE autor.LastName = ''
```

Comment: Not work, it select jast all book names of all autors, and I need to select only book name of selected autor.

Comment: Just add a where condition see edit above.

Comment: And you can remove `autor.LastName` from `SELECT` if you just want the book name